# displaying a dialog in onCreate()

Tags: android, dialog

I may need to display a dialog box, depending upon a certain condition. This condition will have to be resolved before the application can continue. Basically, I need to "pause" the execution of my program until this dialog box has been destroyed. I have tried a bunch of different methods but I am running into a problem where the application continues to execute. Currently, the showDialog is in the onCreate() method of my main activity.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run code only after a button has been pressed, you should use an `onClickListener':

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton(int, java.lang.CharSequence, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.first_run_version_title)
    .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok_menu_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // code to run here
        }
    });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show(); // <-- Forgot this in the original post
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that isn't going to work for me. I need the dialog (or activity) to be launched based on a condition (file not found) at the beginning of my execution. I don't want to have to ask the user to click a button. They are going to get prompted with the option to download the file or exit the application. My application just wont run without this file.

Comment: It sounds like are requiring the user to click a button. If the user clicks the exit button, then the `OnClickListener` just calls `finish()` and if the user clicks the download button then the `OnClickListener` for that button calls whatever code downloads the file.

Comment: Sorry, I actually tried what you suggested but this does not work in onCreate(). It never gets displayed.

Comment: Wait, this actually works. I changed AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); to alert.show() and it works. I do believe this solved my problem. I'll post back in a second. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it downloaded my file but I just have a blank screen after the download was done. I'll play around and see if I can figure out where it got stuck.

Comment: When I copied my code I missed a line. Add `alert.show();` after the code I posted. Glad it's working.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help with that without knowing how you are downloading the file. Are you using an `AsyncTask` or just calling a function or what?

Comment: yes, AsyncTask. The problem, even with your suggestion, is that onCreate continues to execute in the background even while the alert dialog is displayed and that is causing a problem for me. I need it to wait until my file is downloaded before continuing.

Comment: Don't put any more of your code in `onCreate`. Put whatever code is in  `onCreate` either in `onPostExecute` in the `AsyncTask` or in a callback function in your main class.

Comment: So, in your onClick I execute the file download and, i guess cause it uses AsyncTask, the program continues to execute and this is the problem.

Comment: I can't do that either because I don't always have to download this file. Only if it does not exist.

Comment: Then have an if statement, if the file is missing, call the Dialog as I suggested. If the file is already there, directly call the callback function that moves on with the program.

Comment: hmmm, maybe I can rewrite the code so it always uses the AsyncTask even if I don't need to download the file. Sound like a hack, yes?

Comment: Oh, I like that. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It works like a champ. Thanks a bunch for your help. Now I just need to turn this alert dialog into something a bit more user friendly. Thanks again for all your help.